# Convert a matrix into a list by flattening it

Tags: ocaml

I want to convert a matrix (`type matrix = float list list`) into a list (so basically I'm writing a function to concatenate a list of lists, but I'm not allowed to use List.append, List.flatten, etc.).
So for example, into_list [[1.; 2.]; [3.; 4.] = [1.; 2.; 3.; 4.]. I wrote my helper function to append two lists together:

```
let rec append_list (a: float list) (b: float list): float list =
  match a with
  | [] -> b
  | h :: t -> h :: append_list t b
```

right now, my into_list function looks like this:

```
let rec into_list (m : matrix): float list =
  match m with
  | [] -> []
  | h1 :: h2 :: t -> append_list h1 h2 :: into_list t
```

I pretty sure `| h1 :: h2 :: t -> append_list h1 h2 :: into_list t` is wrong but I have no idea how to fix it, right now utop gives me the error message says "Unbound type constructor matrix".

Comment: You give a definition of `matrix` above, but you must not have entered into utop. Hence `matrix` is unbound (i.e., undefined). Put the definition of `matrix` before your function definition and this problem (at least) should go away.

Comment: I tried to define `matrix` before the function and the unbound error is solved, but now it's telling me that `append_list h1 h2` is a `float list` but instead it is expecting a `float` at that position, not sure how to fix that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear `matrix` is simply:

```
type matrix = float list list
```

As such:

```
append_list h1 h2 :: into_list t
```

Would yield `float list list` because the type of `::` is `'a ->` 'a list -> 'a list`.

You're looking for something like a fold, that continually appends the lists into a final `float list`.

```
let rec into_list m = List.fold_left append_list [] m
```

Of course, it doesn't seem like you're allowed to use `List.fold_left`. Replicate that functionality (shown many times here) and you're good to go.

### Tail Recursion

Consider, though, that `append_list` has O(n) runtime *and* stack space complexity. Applying it recursively like this works but gives O(n^2) performance. `append_list` is also not tail-recursive, so even if `into_list` is O(1), so this approach risks a stack overflow on large datasets.

You can see this with:

```
let l = List.init 100_000 float_of_int in
append_list l l
```

Fortunately `append_list` can be made tail-recursive.

```
let append_list lst1 lst2 =
  let rec append_list' acc lst1 lst2 =
    match lst1, lst2 with
    | [], []    -> List.rev acc
    | [], y::ys -> append_list' (y::acc) [] ys
    | x::xs, _  -> append_list' (x::acc) xs lst2
  in
  append_list' [] lst1 lst2
```